# Session ID tokens in django without auth.models.User

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I know that one can set up authentication with the built in django `login(request, user)`, `request.is_authenticated` when the user acquires the `sessionid` cookie, and `authenticate(request, username="foo", password="bar")`.

However, underneath this interface, django creates a `User` object in the database. I am authenticating using other means, namely LDAP. I can opt for just passing the username and password for LDAP every single time, but having a sessionid token would be ideal.

Is there any way to use the same `login(), request.is_authenticated, authenticate()` API but without using the `User` model underneath? Another alternative is fine as well. The one restriction that I have is that I do not want to use another library.

Thanks!

Comment: How concrete is the restriction of not using a library @OneRaynyDay? I am asking because there are some very good and recommended libraries out there and you will not need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: @JohnMoutafis I know that there are many good libraries out there but under a corporate whitelist it will take a lot of work to get the packages approved.

Comment: I guess you can implement a custom solution using a middleware and then disable the django auth system

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, its not possible to use djangos authentication/autorization framework without the `User` model.

In the part where the docs talk about [customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django), it is always centered around the `User` model (even if it is your custom user model).

---

That being said, you could look into something really hackish: creating your [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) that is not stored in the database.

For that you'll probably need custom fields and managers that prevent database calls while still making certain fields available in the model (like `email` and `username`). I never tried it, but it should be possible by overriding djangos default behavior in the right places.

---

But all that effort is probably not worth the trouble. Just write your [own authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) that automatically creates an `User` instance on successful authentication against your LDAP source, so you can *"harness the full potential of the django `User` model"*.